Wireguard VPN connection issue on new router
I use wireguard VPN on Ubuntu to connect remote to the work.
On friday I have got from my ISP new router a since this time the VPN does not work.
The new router is: Vodafone Station Wi-Fi 6
The wireguard conf file I have got from my admin in the work and it works before so I think there is no issue with it.

My work notebook is connected via WIFI to the router and the VPN does not work
When I use my smartphone as hotspot and dont use the same Wifi then the VPN works - So I think that the problem can be on the router
But weird think is that I have wireguard app on my android phone and VPN does work and the phone is connected to the same wifi.

The new router use primary ipv6 but when I tried to disable ipv6 on Ubuntu machine then VPN still does not work.
I tried restart router, log vpn connection (via wg-quick command) but I have no clue what is wrong..

Have you called your ISP?

The solution was set MTU = 1280 to the wireguard config :)
